# Is there some way of escaping characters in Groovy regexes?

Tags: regex, groovy

Is there someway of escaping characters in Groovy regexes? It would be nice to write a single backslash instead of 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need four of them. Two should be enough. e.g. to match anything with a backslash in it.

```
def file = /C:\geo\file.txt/
assert file =~ /.*\\.*/
```

Comment: This code :
`x = "\\geo\\file.txt";
assert x =~ /\\/` says unexpected char :'\'.